# how to plot this waveform

Tags: matlab, waveform

```
 t = 0:.001:.2;
 f=10;
 x=sin(2*pi*f*t);
 n=15;
 y=sin(2*pi*n*t);
 x(x<=0) = 0;
 plot(t,x);
  hold on
 plot(t,y);
```

this is the waveform that i need 
    togenerate:

[image: I want output like this]

and this is the waveform i have so far:

[image]

the first part its a simple sin but the second part when the sin doesn't go 
    into the negative part I am struggling with when I set it the negative 
    interval to 0 its going to be 0 for the whole interval not just for a point

Answer (score 1):

The supplied image has two sine waves plotted next to each other, of which the one has a negative sign.

How about this:

```
t = -4:0.1:4;
y = 0.5.*sign(t).*sin(t*4)
plot(t,y)
```

Comment: Alternatively, `y = 0.5 * sin(abs(t*4));`

Comment: the 2nd image which I posted is wrong the first one is what I need,that expression will do something like: it will start at a point and it will start to increase but in my image i need it to decrease from 0 to -0.5

Comment: Look at the solutions me and @Zizy gave, as it shows you exactly how to recreate the first image.

Comment: When I run it it gives me some other result not my image,but ty

Comment: Matching the period `T = 2` seen in the picture: `y = 0.5 * sin(abs(pi*t));`